# How to make s3 bucket public in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have an already created bucket in amazon s3. I want to make its content publicly available without any authentication. I have tried from documents of boto

> To set a canned ACL for a bucket, use the set_acl method of the Bucket object. The argument passed to this method must be one of the four permissable canned policies named in the list CannedACLStrings contained in acl.py. For example, to make a bucket readable by anyone:
>
> > > b.set_acl('public-read')

It is not working. I still cant access my files publicly. However setting acl to `public-read` for individual files is working.

I want to make it public from python as I don't have access to s3 console.

I want to make whole bucket publicly readable.

My code is

```
    conn = boto.connect_s3(
        aws_access_key_id = access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
        host = 's3.amazonaws.com',
        #is_secure=False,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )
bucket = conn.get_bucket('media_library')
bucket.set_acl('public-read')
```

Comment: My bucket is already created. Also that doesn't seem python code.

Comment: do you have link for your bucket?

Comment: yes https://media_library.s3.amazonaws.com/public/users/Integrators/102ba277-aa60-4ec6-9e7d-84c8522d0b9d/test1-clientside/cp-2.png

Comment: try this - import boto.s3
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1')  # or region of choice
bucket = conn.get_bucket('public')
key = bucket.lookup('users/Integrators/102ba277-aa60-4ec6-9e7d-84c8522d0b9d/test1-clientside/cp-2.png')
key.set_acl('public-read')

Comment: That is already working, as I said in question.  I want all files to be public

Comment: have you set bucket policy? if yes, what is the policy contains? To make access all the files in bucket as public you just need the correct policy to set

Comment: I have done following `bucket.set_acl('public-read')` to set public-read policy. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116430/discussion-between-rohan-khude-and-sarvesh).

Answer (score 5):

You will need to create a **Bucket Policy**, which defines permissions on the bucket as a whole.

See 'Bucket Policy' in: [Managing Access to S3 Resources (Access Policy Options)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html#access-control-resources-manage-permissions-basics)

You can do this via `boto` in Python with [`put_bucket_policy()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_policy):

> **put_bucket_policy(**kwargs)**
>
> Replaces a policy on a bucket. If the bucket already has a policy, the one in this request completely replaces it.
>
> **Request Syntax**
>
> `response = client.put_bucket_policy(Bucket='string', Policy='string')`

See [Bucket Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) to find a suitable policy.

Here is a policy that **makes the whole bucket publicly readable** (just insert your own bucket name):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```