# Making public s3 artifacts from AWS code build

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

How to make the artifacts uploaded to s3 as part of an `aws code build` public by default? I'm experimenting build automation. At present the build is successful; however, the artifact created isn't public and hence I can't share the link (as part of a mail). By default, the server side encryption is set at `Using AWS KMS master key: aws/s3 (default).` When tried removing the `encryption key` from the `advanced settings` section of the aws code build config, it gave an error. I'm planning to run an aws lambda function that will send a mail with link of the artifact at the end of the build as part of the aws code pipeline.

**Edit:** 
I tried adding the following as the permission but it didn't help:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
   {
    "Sid":"AddPerm",
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
   }
  ]
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196758/how-to-make-s3-bucket-public-in-python)

From S3 if I manually go and select `none` as the encryption, the link does become downloadable. However I need a programmatic way to do this as I'm trying to automate the entire process as part of the build automation. So far I'm not able to achieve this via `boto3` too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could use AWS Lambda, triggered when your build artifact is uploaded to a specific S3 bucket - the Lambda would use the S3 API to modify the S3 object permissions. Or you could configure AWS CodeBuild to send a build notification via SNS and respond to that notification by modifying the build artifact permissions.

Comment: Thanks! I shall try that.

Comment: You could also investigate applying an S3 bucket policy that makes all content in the bucket publicly readable but I don't know if that's acceptable to you depending on other content in the bucket (example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding required policy from the link mentioned, however, I see the same error when I tried to download from the link. If I manually unselect encryption, it works. The problem is that I'm not able to do that from boto3 and hence cannot automate the process.

Comment: Updated the question with more information. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! I got a reply in aws developer forum as follows:

> Thank you for this feature request, I have passed it to the team for further review. Your feedback is very much appreciated.

Which means the feature is probably not present now.

This is the [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=256656) to the AWS dev forum.
Anyways, there's a **workaround** for the time being. You can see that too in the same link or **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266057/1349159)** with more details.